# búsqueda con acentos, diéresis, etc angularjs

Tags: php, javascript, html, angularjs, json

tengo este buscador con paginacion que funciona bien pero cuando la cadena lleva  acentos, diéresis, etc  no los encuentra alguna ayuda

```js
var application = angular.module('ngPagination', [])
.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, inicio) {
     if (input!==undefined) {
         inicio = +inicio;
         return input.slice(inicio);
     }
    };
})
.filter('pagFilter', function () {
 return filtrar;
})
.service('$paginationRegister', function($injector){
 function registerMetodos () {
  this.page_id = '';
  this.variable = '';
 }
 registerMetodos.prototype.set = function (id) {
  this.page_id = 'pag_'+id;
  this.variable = id;
 };
 registerMetodos.prototype.get = function () {
  return this.page_id;
 };
 registerMetodos.prototype.getDataNotation = function () {
  return this.variable;
 };
 registerMetodos.prototype.getSizeNotation = function () {
  return this.page_id + '.pageSize';
 };
 registerMetodos.prototype.getPagesNotation = function () {
  return this.page_id + '.pages';
 };
 registerMetodos.prototype.getDataLengthNotation = function () {
  return this.page_id + '.dataLength';
 };
 registerMetodos.prototype.getCurrentNotation = function () {
  return this.page_id + '.pageCurrent';
 };

 registerMetodos.prototype.getNextNotation = function () {
  return this.page_id + '.nextPage';
 };
 registerMetodos.prototype.getBeforeNotation = function () {
  return this.page_id + '.beforePage';
 };
 registerMetodos.prototype.getSearchNotation = function () {
  return this.variable+'_search';
 };

 return function() {
  return $injector.instantiate(registerMetodos);
 };
});

var getPaginas = function (datos, size){
 var pag=0;
 if (datos!==undefined) {pag = Math.ceil(datos.length/size);}
    return pag;
};

var getVarname = function (RepeatValue) {
 var variable = RepeatValue.replace(' in ','~');
 variable = variable.replace(' | ','~');
 variable = variable.replace('|','~');
 variable = variable.split('~');
 return variable[1].replace(' ','');
};

// DIRECTIVA PARA PAGINAR
application.directive('ngPagination', function($compile, $parse, $paginationRegister){

 return {
  terminal: true, // NOS SIRVE POR SI TENEMOS OTRA DIRECTIVA DENTRO DEL  NG-REPEAT
        multiElement: true,
        priority: 20,
     restrict: 'A', // RESTRINGIDO SOLO A ATTRIBUTO
  scope: false, // NOS DICE QUE EL SCOPE ES EL MISMO DEL CONTROLADOR

  compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
   // COMPILE RETURNED LINKED
   return function(scope, element, attr){
    var registro = new $paginationRegister();
    var dataNotation = getVarname(element.attr('ng-pagination'));
    registro.set(dataNotation);
    $parse(registro.get()).assign(scope, {pageCurrent:0, pageSize:5, pages:1, dataLength:1, nextPage: function(){}, beforePage: function(){}});

    // AGREGANDO ng-repeat Y QUITANDO ng-pagination PARA EVITAR LOOP
    element.attr('ng-pagination', element.attr('ng-pagination') + " | pagFilter:"+registro.getSearchNotation());
    element.attr('ng-pagination', element.attr('ng-pagination') + " | startFrom:"+registro.getCurrentNotation()+"*"+registro.getSizeNotation()+" | limitTo:"+registro.getSizeNotation());
    element.attr('ng-repeat', element.attr('ng-pagination'));
    element.removeAttr('ng-pagination');

    // NUMERO DE DATOS POR PAGINA
    var size = Number(element.attr('ng-pagination-size')) + 0;
    if(angular.isDefined(size) && angular.isNumber(size) && size>0){
     $parse(registro.getSizeNotation()).assign(scope, Number(size));
    }

    // NUMERO DE PAGINAS
    var paginas = getPaginas($parse(dataNotation)(scope), $parse(registro.getSizeNotation())(scope));
    if(paginas!==undefined && paginas!==''){
     $parse(registro.getPagesNotation()).assign(scope, Number(paginas));
    }

    // EVENTO WATCH PARA CUANDO CAMBIA LA VARIABLE DE LOS DATOS
    scope.$watch(dataNotation, function () {
     var data = $parse(dataNotation)(scope);
     var paginas = getPaginas(data, $parse(registro.getSizeNotation())(scope));
     $parse(registro.getPagesNotation()).assign(scope, Number(paginas));
     $parse(registro.getDataLengthNotation()).assign(scope, data.length);
    });

    $compile(element)(scope);
   };
  }
 };
});


// DIRECTIVA PARA LOS CONTROLES DE PAGINACION
application.directive('ngPaginationControl', function($compile, $parse, $paginationRegister){
 // VARIABLES PARA CREAR ESTILO
 var fondo='#03A9F4';
 var fondoHover='#286090';
 var color='white';
 var alto= '25px';
 var borderRadius=6;

 function CreateStyle() {
  var estilo = '<style>'+
  '.pagination-panel{'+
   'position: relative;'+
   'display: inline-block;'+
   'height: '+alto+';'+

   'background-color: '+fondo+';'+
   'border: 0px solid #2e6da4;'+
   // 'box-shadow: inset 0 -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);'+
   'border-radius:'+borderRadius+'px;'+
  '}'+
  '.pagination-panel .indicator{'+
   'color: '+color+';'+
   'font-weight: bold;'+
   'font-size: 12px;'+
   'padding: 0px 10px;'+
   'line-height: 0;'+
  '}'+
  '.pagination-panel button{'+
   'background-color: darkblue;'+
   'color: '+color+';'+
   // 'width: 40px;'+
   // 'box-shadow: inset 0 -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);'+
   // 'height: '+alto+';'+
   'height: 100%;'+
   // 'padding-bottom:2px;'+
   'border: none;'+
   'cursor: pointer;'+
  '}'+
  '.pagination-panel button:hover{'+
   'background-color: '+fondoHover+';'+
  '}'+
  '.pagination-panel button:first-child{'+
   'border-radius: '+(borderRadius-2)+'px 0px 0px '+(borderRadius-2)+'px;'+
   'border-right: none;'+
  '}'+
  '.pagination-panel button:last-child{'+
   'border-radius: 0px '+(borderRadius-2)+'px '+(borderRadius-2)+'px 0px;'+
   'border-left: none;'+
  '}'+
  '.pagination-panel button[disabled]{'+
   'color: #506E7D;'+
   'background-color: #D1D5D8;'+
   'cursor: not-allowed;'+
  '}'+
  '</style>';
  angular.element(document.head).prepend(estilo);
 }
 return {
  priority:10,
  restrict:'E',
  scope:false,

  compile: function (element, attrs) {
   var registro = new $paginationRegister();
   if(element.attr('pagination-id')===undefined || element.attr('pagination-id')===''){
    throw "directiva NG-PAGINATION-CONTROL requiere atributo pagination-id\n";
   }else{
    registro.set(element.attr('pagination-id'));
   }

   if(element.attr('background')!==undefined && element.attr('background')!==''){
    fondo = element.attr('background');
   }
   if(element.attr('background-hover')!==undefined && element.attr('background-hover')!==''){
    fondoHover = element.attr('background-hover');
   }
   if(element.attr('color')!==undefined && element.attr('color')!==''){
    color = element.attr('color');
   }
   if(element.attr('height')!==undefined && element.attr('height')!==''){
    alto = element.attr('height');
   }
   CreateStyle();

   // COMPILE RETURNED LINKED
   return function (scope, element, atributos) {
    var dataNotation = registro.getDataNotation();
    var resultados = filtrar($parse(dataNotation)(scope), $parse(registro.getSearchNotation())(scope));
    var controls = angular.element('<div class="pagination-panel">'+
     '<button ng-click="'+registro.getBeforeNotation()+'()" type="button"'+
     'ng-disabled="'+registro.getCurrentNotation()+'<=0"><<</button>'+

     '<small class="indicator">{{'+registro.getCurrentNotation()+'+1}} - {{'+registro.getPagesNotation()+'}}</small>'+

     '<button ng-click="'+registro.getNextNotation()+'()" type="button"'+
     'ng-disabled="'+registro.getCurrentNotation()+'>=('+registro.getDataLengthNotation()+'/'+registro.getSizeNotation()+')-1">>></button>'+
    '</div>');

    $parse(registro.getBeforeNotation()).assign(scope, function () {
     var actual = $parse(registro.getCurrentNotation())(scope);
     actual = actual-1;
     $parse(registro.getCurrentNotation()).assign(scope, actual);
    });

    $parse(registro.getNextNotation()).assign(scope, function () {
     var actual = $parse(registro.getCurrentNotation())(scope);
     actual = actual+1;
     $parse(registro.getCurrentNotation()).assign(scope, actual);
    });

    $compile(controls)(scope);
    element.replaceWith(controls);
   };
  }
 };
});


// METODO PARA FILTRAR DATOS DE UN JSON
function filtrar(DATOS, FILTRO) {
 var busqueda=[];
 if(FILTRO==='' || FILTRO===undefined){
  return DATOS;
 }
 angular.forEach(DATOS, function(fila) {
  for(var key in fila){
   var propiedad = fila[key];
   if (esIgualFn(propiedad, FILTRO)) { busqueda.push(fila); return; }
  }
 });
 return busqueda;
}
function esIgualFn(propiedad, filtro) {
 if(angular.isString(propiedad)){propiedad = propiedad.toLowerCase();}
 if(angular.isString(filtro)){filtro = filtro.toLowerCase();}
 if(angular.isString(propiedad) && propiedad.length<100 && (angular.isString(filtro) || angular.isNumber(filtro)) ) {
  if (propiedad.indexOf(filtro)>-1) {return true;}
 }
 return false;
}

application.directive('ngPaginationSearch', function($compile, $parse, $paginationRegister){
 return {
  priority: 5,
  restrict:'A',
  scope:false,

  compile: function(iElement, iAttrs){
   // ESTA DIRECTIVA SOLO PUEDE SER USADA POR UN ELEMENTO INPUT
   if(iElement[0].localName.toLowerCase()!='input'){
    throw "DIRECTIVE NG-PAGINATION-SEARCH SOLO PUEDE SER USADA POR UN ELEMENTO INPUT\n";
   }

   var registro = new $paginationRegister();
   if(iElement.attr('ng-pagination-search')===undefined || iElement.attr('ng-pagination-search')===''){
    throw "DIRECTIVE NG-PAGINATION-SEARCH NOT VALUE\n";
   }else{
    registro.set(iElement.attr('ng-pagination-search'));
   }

   return function (scope, element, attrs){
    var modelo = registro.getSearchNotation();
    element.attr('ng-model',modelo);
    element.removeAttr('ng-pagination-search');

    // EVENTO WATCH PARA EL CAMBIO DEL INPUT EN BUSQUEDA
    var dataNotation = registro.getDataNotation();
    var tempDataNotation = dataNotation+'_tmp';
    $parse(modelo).assign(scope,'');
    scope.$watch(modelo, function () {
     // CAPTURANDO EL VALOR DEL INPUT
     var paginas=0;
     var filtro = $parse(modelo)(scope);
     // AL MOMENTO DE BUSQUEDA MANDAR EL CURRENT PAGE A 0 PARA QUE SE VAYA A LA PRIMERA PAGINA
     $parse(registro.getCurrentNotation()).assign(scope, 0);
     if(filtro===undefined || filtro===''){
      paginas = getPaginas($parse(dataNotation)(scope), $parse(registro.getSizeNotation())(scope));
      $parse(registro.getDataLengthNotation()).assign(scope, ($parse(dataNotation)(scope)).length);
      $parse(registro.getPagesNotation()).assign(scope, Number(paginas));
     }else{
      var resultados = filtrar($parse(dataNotation)(scope), filtro);
      paginas = getPaginas(resultados, $parse(registro.getSizeNotation())(scope));
      $parse(registro.getDataLengthNotation()).assign(scope, resultados.length);
      $parse(registro.getPagesNotation()).assign(scope, Number(paginas));
     }
    });
    $compile(element)(scope);
   };
  }
 };
});
```

Comment: puedes hacer un truco, los datos con acentos y sin acentos, cuando busques busca en los dos una especie de or y te mostrara lo que quieres, pero si me preguntas a mi creo que esta bien la busqueda de como la programastes pasaria lo mismo con caracteres como al "ñ"

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda con la ñ no tengo problemas

Answer (score 0):

Puedes normalizar el texto de tu búsqueda, por ejemplo:

```
var termino = 'Búsqueda en stacoverflow';
var busqueda = "busqueda";

termino = termino.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
termino = termino.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
if(texto.toLowerCase().indexOf(busqueda.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
 console.log('encontrado');
}
```